# Using PHP foreach How to get first item from DB then others

Tags: php

how can I get first item from db by foreach

```
$posts = new Posts();    
$post = $posts->feature_post($conn);
foreach($post as $feature) { ?>
```

my html code is different for 1st item. so I need to get 1st item then other item,
how I can do it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to count the items as you handle them.

Comment: what is your ```$post``` variable structure? just wanted to know that's an ```array``` or ```object``` ?

Comment: All this needs is a simple flag you set before the loop, and then check and flip inside ... `$first = true; foreach(...) { if($first) { dosomething(); } else { dootherstuff(); } $first = false; }`

Answer (score 1):

To get the first item of an array, you can use the reset function

> http://php.net/manual/fr/function.reset.php

```
<?php
$posts = new Posts();    
$listPost = $posts->feature_post($conn);
$firstPost = reset($listPost);
...
```

Also if you want to know if you loop through the first element and if the keys of your arrays are 0,1,2,3 etc..

```
<?php
foreach($array as $key => $cell) {
    if ($key === 0) {
        // this is your first element
        ....
    }
}
```

If the keys of your array are not numeric indexes but you don't intend to use them, you can obtain such array by using the [array_values](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-values.php) function

Comment: then how to loop $key 1,2,4 etcc inside foreach

Comment: what do you mean ? The foreach loop through all values of your array so inside the foreach you just do what you want outside the if that checks that this is the first iteration

Comment: thanks I found my answers